# Which preposition to use when considering the "social media" as a virtual counterpart of the "real" world?

Tags: prepositions, context, social-media

So, what is then the correct distinction between the "in"and "on" preposition, when connected with the "social media" as a virtual space/entity - in oppposition to the "real" - physical reality...

Example sentence:

> "the reality is to live in, and not to shine up to others {**in/on**} social media..."

Comment: Can you give an example sentence showing the context in which you are considering using "in social media" or "on social media"?

Comment: „the reality is to live in, and not to shine up to others <in> social  media...“ the respective preposition in question is marked by arrows <>

Comment: ... but I would be pleased to recomendations,  regarding any of here used clausal elements...